# Trying to run my Next.js project on my server

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

how are you? I'm trying to run my Next.js project on my server, but every time I execute any command for initialization, it returns this error. Does anyone know what it could be?

npm run build

> apice-fronte0.1.0 build
>
> next build
> unhandledRejection RangeError: WebAssembly.instantiate() : Out of memory: wasm memory
> at lazylihttp (eval at requireWithFakeGlobalScope (/home1/thasolut/public_html/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@edge-runtime/primit
> ives/load.js:65:3), :9988:32)

I'm trying to get this project to run on my server, but without success.

Comment: your server RAM (Random Access Memory) is not enouph to build your next.js app. Try to upgrade